# will re-installing windows without formatting and running anti virus remove viruses?

Tags: windows, virus

I suspected I had virus in my system. I downloaded the trial version of Kaspersky internet Security 2013, updated the DB and ran a full system scan. It identified the viruses and removed them and subsequent scans showed the system clean.

Just to be sure, I formatted the windows drive and reinstalled windows. I have some files that need to be backed up in the other drives and i cannot format them.

Will the reinstallation disable any lingering viruses or should I format the whole hard disk to get rid of the viruses completely?

Comment: The virus won't run anymore, but the file will still exists, which if ran will infect your system.  So my advice, format the system, and get rid of the infection.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime we re-install Windows pretty much all viruses will be removed. But really, you should be able to remove most virus without having to do anything to your computer. AVG Free is a really good security program that lasts forever, and seems to find every virus. That is what I use and we have never had to re-install Windows. AVG does a great job.

AVG finds the corrupted files, replaces them, and will remove the original virus file.

Now, that said, if you do re-install Windows and recover your files from a backup, then the executable file that caused the virus could still be there. If you have to recover your documents, be sure to run AVG or some other virus program BEFORE you do anything else.

Regards,

Ace Legend.

Answer (score 0):

For typical viruses on a Windows computer, running a good system inspection and virus removal product (such as your running of Kaspersky) will be sufficient. A complete re-install of a system due to virus infection is usually a last resort step due to *There is nothing that can save this computer* reasoning.

However, there are still some very small subset of viruses that can linger on the Boot record of a hard drive which a typical re-install of Windows **will not** get rid of. You would need to format and recreate the boot partition, or use a rootkit virus scanner.

Another infection vector includes websites or already compromised files that you might restore to the new 'clean' system. Be sure to inspect (virus scan) and clean any files you move over from the infected system before opening or using them

Programs or software I have found useful in detecting and removing viruses from 'hosed' Windows systems:

- [Kaspersky Live CD](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208282173)
- [Bitdefender Rescue](http://download.bitdefender.com/rescue_cd/)
- [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)
- [Super Anti-Sypware](http://www.superantispyware.com/)
- [Sophos Anti Rootkit](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-anti-rootkit.aspx)
- [TddsKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208283363) (rootkit)

*Question: Will the re - installation disable any lingering viruses or should I format the whole hard disk to get rid of the viruses completely?*

**Short Answer:** Typically, yes. However certain viruses may linger after a re-install, or may be reintroduced to the system after restoring from backups.